# The Corbino effect

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-hall-effect

How exactly does the Corbino effect take place? Are there any mathematical expressions behind its proof? 
I read from Wikipedia that logarithmic spheres are formed. How is this possible mathematically?

Please explain with basic maths as I am not yet an expert in mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

The [Corbino effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect#The_Corbino_effect) is the same phenomenon as the [homopolar generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_generator). In both cases in a rotating conductive material and under the influence of an external magnetic field electrons get deflected.

It's the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) $ \vec F = q \vec v \times \vec B $ inside conductors. Wikipedia about the [Hall effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect#Theory):

> > The Hall effect is due to the nature of the current in a conductor. Current consists of the movement of many small charge carriers, typically electrons, holes, ions... When a magnetic field is present, these charges experience a force, called the Lorentz force.

Compairing the sketches from both the Corbino effect (first sketch) and homopolar generator (second sketch) one see the congruence:

[image] [image]

Comment: Any figure depicting it? And any kind of senseful formula?

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu It's better now?

Comment: Probably yes...